# Angular 6 - Conditionally change Attributes of Element in HTML Header

Tags: android, html, angular, google-chrome, angular6

I recently found out that you can alter Chromes header on Android by putting this in the HTML header.

```
<meta name="theme-color" content="#1ee078">
```

This works perfectly. But I want the `content` color to be dynamic based on the current theme.

How would you make the color of this `meta` tag dynamic, if you would have the current theme color as a variable in e.g. the `AppComponent`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Within Angular there is a built in API to edit [`meta`](https://angular.io/api/platform-browser/Meta) tags. `@angular/platform-browser/meta`

You can use the [`updateTag`](https://angular.io/api/platform-browser/Meta#updatetag) function.

You should be able to do something like;

```js
import { Meta } from '@angular/platform-browser';

constructor(
  private meta: Meta
) { }

ngOnInit() {
  this.meta.updateTag({ 
    name: 'theme-color', 
    content: '#1ee078' 
  });
}
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with the API. But this seems interesting.

Answer (score 1):

You could try this one. Depending on your page, it might work. :)

```
var meta=document.createElement('meta');
meta.name='theme-color';

meta.setAttribute('content', '#1ee078');

document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(meta);
```